# KendoUI Autocomplete Submit Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, kendo-ui

I am using a KendoUI Autocomplete that is encased in a `<form>`. If you press enter when the autocomplete options are open, the enter only closes the options, and you have to hit enter again to submit the form. Listening for keypresses on the input to check when enter is pressed doesn't even work; the first enter is never registered. I tried tapping into the `change` event of the KendoUI control and the `close` event so as to execute javascript to submit the form manually, but I can't get anything that makes the first enter submit the form without bad side effects. Here is the html:

```
<form action="@Url.Content("~/Metro/UserAction/SearchLibrary")" id="searchform" method="get" name="searchform">
<div>
    <input name="keywords" id="products" style="width: 300px; margin-right: 10px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px;" />
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the control:

```
    var autocomplete = $("#products").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataTextField: "SearchTerm",
        filter: "contains",
        template: '<span>#: data.ContentName #</span>',
        minLength: 3,
        dataSource: [],
        select: onSelect,
        change: function (e) {
            if (search) {
                if ($("#products").is(":focus")) {
                    $("#searchform").submit();
                }
            }
            else {
                search = true;
            }
        }
    }).data("kendoAutoComplete");

    $("#products").focusout(function () {
        autocomplete.close();
    });
```

I'll add that the focusout was necessary because otherwise the autocomplete did not close... I don't know why this was the case because the demos close and don't need any additional logic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What is `search`? Do you have it initially defined?

When I've tried your code it worked fine without `focusout`, one single click,... as soon as I have defined search. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/hMtZ6/) what I've tried:

```
var autocomplete = $("#products").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "SearchTerm",
    filter: "contains",
    template: '<span>#: data.ContentName #</span>',
    minLength: 1,
    dataSource: ds,
    change: function (e) {
        if ($("#products").is(":focus")) {
            $("#searchform").submit();
        }
    }
}).data("kendoAutoComplete");
```

Comment: I agree that your fiddle works as I need my code to. However, for some reason, my dropdown autocomplete will not close when you click on the page it resides in. It hangs open, which is why I needed the `focusout` bit. This messes everything up because it fires the change event, which somehow gets past the `$("#products").is(":focus"))` and then submits the form if you click out of the page. Any ideas why my suggestions won't close when focus is lost?

Not sure what you mean about `search`. Where do you see an element titled `search` in my code?

Datasource is added after an ajax call.

Comment: Stupid of me... Duh. Search is a var that is initially defined to allow me to update the value of the autocomplete without also submitting another search query. For the purposes of this question it should be eliminated.